# Can't solve mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' PhpMyAdmin erorr

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, web-development-server

I am trying to connect to my db through phpmyadmin but I can't get connected no matter what solutions I try.

I am able to connect to the phpmyadmin screen but when I try to access my webpage I am met with the error.

Here it is expanded.

[mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): page error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gueIv.png)

I'm trying to access the path xampp/htdocs/pfs (my site).

I am using port 4306

[xampp config panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNNvE.png)

my username/password is root and no password

[config.inc.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEDW0.png)

[db_connection.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOw4T.png)

Here's my phpmyadmin root user information too

[phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYMZL.png)

Is there another file path the phpmyadmin reads username/password information from that I'm missing ? Or am I trying to access my webpage in the incorrect way ? I can't figure this one out.

If anyone can help I'd appreciate it.

I've tried about 20 thread solutions from stackoverflow that were titled with the mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): error

I am expecting to be able to view my webpage through htdocs and then be able to show CRUD statements.

Here's what I tested.

- Changed port to 4306 in xampp config, config.inc.php and sql my.ini file
- Changed password to root & " " in both db_connection.php and config.inc.php (this stopped me from accessing phpmyadmin altogether)
- Changed hostname to localhost:4306 (this stopped me from accessing phpmyadmin altogether)

Answer (score -1):

you need to add database name in mysqli function call:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","database_name");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply I appreciate the help,

unfortunately it doesn't work still,

I have servername, username & pass but I added the db name but still no change 

Here's my conn string

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

Comment: and you have created a database (db) in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: Yeah there's definitely the same named db in phpmyadmin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).